# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, axios

SyntaxError: Unexpected tokenとエラーが出ます。

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import SearchForm from './SearchForm';
import GeocodeResult from './GeocodeResult';
import Map from './Map';

const GEOCODE_ENDPOINT = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  setErrorMessage(message) {
    this.setState({
      address: message,
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0,
    });
  }

  handlePlaceSubmit(place) {
    axios
    .get(GEOCODE_ENDPOINT, { params: { address: place } })
    .then((results) => {
      console.log(results);
      const data = results.data;
      const result = data.results[0];
      switch (data.status) {
        case 'OK': {
          const location = results.geometry.location;
          this.setState({
            address: result.formatted_address,
            lat: location.lat,
            lng: location.lng,
          });
          break;
        }
        case 'ZERO_RESULTS': {
          this.setErrorMessage('結果が見つかりませんでした');
          break;
        }
        default: {
          this.setErrorMessage('エラーが発生しました');
          }
        }
      })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.setErrorMessage('通信に失敗しました');
          });
      }

      const location = results.geometry.location;
      this.setState({
        address: result.formatted_address,
        lat: location.lat,
        lng: location.lng,
      });
    };
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>緯度経度検索</h1>
        <SearchForm onSubmit={place => this.handlePlaceSubmit(place)} />
        <GeocodeResult
          address={this.state.address}
          lat={this.state.lat}
          lng={this.state.lng}
        />
        <Map lat={this.state.lat} lng={this.state.lng} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

とコードを書いて、実行すると、

```
ERROR in ./src/components/App.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (56:12)

  54 |       }
  55 |
> 56 |       const location = results.geometry.location;
     |             ^
  57 |       this.setState({
  58 |         address: result.formatted_address,
  59 |         lat: location.lat,
```

とエラーが出ました。const location = results.geometry.location;の行が何かおかしいのかな？と思いましたが原因がわからず。。。そのほかのカッコの数かもしれません。。。
エラーの箇所を指摘していただければと思います。

Answer (score 2):

インデントを合わせてみたところ、`App`クラス定義の中で、`const location = results.geometry.location;`の行から、`render`メソッド定義の前の行までの記述が、メソッド定義の外に出てしまっているようです。

```es6
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // 略
  }

  setErrorMessage(message) {
    // 略
  }

  handlePlaceSubmit(place) {
    axios
    .get(GEOCODE_ENDPOINT, { params: { address: place } })
    .then((results) => {
      // 略
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.setErrorMessage('通信に失敗しました');
    });
  }

  const location = results.geometry.location; // ここから
  this.setState({
    address: result.formatted_address,
    lat: location.lat,
    lng: location.lng,
  });
};
} // ここまで

  render() {
    // 略
  }
}
```